# how do I set compilingflags in a makefile?

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile

I'm used to program in IDEs, but switched to vim and plugins recently. Now I try to write a makefile for a c++ project, but somehow if I run `make` I always get the error

```
g++    -c -o *.o createOutput.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/thread:35:0,
                 from createOutput.cpp:5:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
 #error This file requires compiler and library support for the \
  ^
```

This is my makefile:

```
CC = clang++

# compiler flags
CFLAGS = -O3 -Wall -Werror -std=c++11
CFLAGS_SFML = -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system

all: program.exe clean

program.exe: *.o
    $(CC) -o program.exe *.o $(CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS_SFML) 

getInput.o: getInput.cpp
    $(CC) -c getInput.cpp $(CFLAGS) 

createOutput.o: createOutput.cpp
    $(CC) -c createOutput.cpp $(CFLAGS) 

main.o: main.cpp
    $(CC) -c main.cpp $(CFLAGS)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm *.o
    @echo clean done
```

Where is my error? Why is it using `g++` instead of `clang`? And why isn't it using the `-std=c++11` parameter? Sorry for the beginner questions, I unfortunately can't find a solution with google.

Comment: `*.o` doesn't match anything before you create any object files (the first time you compile) so your `program.exe` target doesn't work correctly. This makefile isn't properly written. You want to construct the list of `.o` files from the list of source files and use that variable/list in the prerequisite of the `program.exe` target. There are examples of this **all** over this site and the internet. That said you don't even need that as the built-in make rules will do what you need if you define the flags and prerequisites correctly.

Comment: CC is the compiler for C.  At a guess probably need to set CXX for C++.  You also probably need the .cpp.o rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`make` tried to make target '*.o'.

So, instead of that, you can specify sources list explicitly:

```
CC = clang++

#compiler flags
CFLAGS = -O3 -Wall -Werror -std=c++11
CFLAGS_SFML = -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
SRCS = getInput.cpp createOutput.cpp main.cpp
OBJS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)

all: program.exe

program.exe: $(OBJS)
        $(CC) -o program.exe *.o $(CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS_SFML)

getInput.o: getInput.cpp
        $(CC) -c getInput.cpp $(CFLAGS)

createOutput.o: createOutput.cpp
        $(CC) -c createOutput.cpp $(CFLAGS)

main.o: main.cpp
        $(CC) -c main.cpp $(CFLAGS)

.PHONY : clean
clean:
        rm *.o
        @echo clean done
```

Note definition of variables `OBJS` and `SRCS`.

Answer (score 3):

You want to set `CXXFLAGS`, that gets picked up automatically by `make` (and sent to your compiler  (*eg* `g++`, `clang++`, *etc*).

Comment: but I want to use clang++. What exactely do you mean by automatically?

Comment: The compilers don't pay any attention to that variable. `make` does. This answer is, somewhat, correct but misses the major point which is that the recipes in the makefile aren't being used at all.

Comment: @EtanReisner Thanks, quite right.  Edited answer accordingly.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, shouldn't have used the `S` word.  *convention* would've been more accurate.